# How do you get event Pokémon like Keldeo?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I've never gotten any Pokémon (other than Mewtwo) from events, so I don't have clue about how they really work. =)

As [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Keldeo_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) and other sites are saying, Keldeo is **"… currently the final officially-revealed Pokémon in National Pokédex order."**

But how do I actually *get* Keldeo? Do I need keep my eye on Entralink all day? Do they have a site for it? Will I get an email?

I would be really grateful if someone could explain it to me.

(If it matters, I have Pokémon White for the DS.)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to ask?

Comment: Pokemon White is actually a DS game, not a 3DS game

Comment: @AshleyNunn i know =) but thank you for the right point, i just said my console (nintendo 3DS), not that the game is for this console only, if it matters... if is a DS, DS-light or 3ds, was just saying like the one who say that is playing fifa on ps3 (even if its the fifa for ps2). I am sorry if i made some mistake writing it.

Comment: @Wipqozn idk WHY you got upvote, and idk why my question was not understandable, i ask 2 or 3 times, if someone could explain to me how an event in pokemon (in white if posible) works. Because i want Keldeo, and i don't know how could i look for it. just read again, i sit 3 samples over there. Thank you for your comment =)

Comment: @Wipqozn making just an append: If you say why you didn't understand, i could try make it more clear, but for me atm is very clear, so please, tell me how can i get this question a better "visual" thank you in advance =)

Comment: Without meaning to offend, a lot of the issue comes from your formatting and your grammar. The formatting makes it hard to read, and the grammar makes it hard to understand. @ashleynunn was able to fix up your question so it's understandable, although I'm not sure if that was your original question.

Comment: @Wipqozn Thank you, i will try get better in the next question. Sorry if i offend you too. As you can see, i am not English is not my main language. +1 for your explanation about my mistakes =)

Comment: I assumed as much. I didn't mean to offend you with my original question, I simply wanted some clarifaction. So apologies if you took offense to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Event](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Event) page on Bulbapedia has a list of generally how each event pokemon is distriubted. Keldeo is currently listed as unknown, which indicates that there has never been an event that allowed people to catch it. I know event pokemon have been given away over Nintendo Wi-Fi, through in-store giveaways, and by transfers from other games, among other methods. The only way to know how Keldeo will be released is to watch for news that it will be given away somehow.

Comment: Do you know how could i track those information ?

Comment: I noticed when looking at Bulbapedia that there is a [news site](http://bulbanews.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Main_Page), so that might be good to watch.

Comment: WoW! i didn't saw that!!! Amazing feed, ty.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are home events and GameStop events.

Home events can be performed by going to mystery gift and playing it, click one of the three and you're done.

The GameStop events are at a local participating GameStop, ask one of the people at the desk for the info and then follow their instructions.

You can get info for event pokemon [here](http://www.pokemon.com).

Comment: While this particular answer does offer a bit of new information, it is already covered in the other answer. Also I believe that this covers Pokemon X and Y not Pokemon White and Black as Gamestop is no longer offering these promotions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually surprised this has so few answers, and not too extensive ones even...

Most Event Pokémon (Mew, Celebi, arguably Manaphy and Phione, Jirachi, Deoxys, Shaymin, Darkrai, Arceus, Keldeo, Meloetta, Genesect and 3 more since X/Y) are not obtainable in game by any means other than Trading (from someone who did get it by one of the methods detailed hereafter), Cheat devices (such as Action Replay) or glitches (such as the Tweaking glitch in D/P). The few exceptions require a side game such as Pokémon Ranger, *or as I state below (via official distribution)*.

---

They are, however, being distributed occasionally by different means, usually via either Wi-Fi/Internet, Local distributions by Stores (GameStop, Walmart, hobby stores) or at special events (Pokemon Days, World Championships, ...) or Global Link. These distributions are usually live for several weeks, unless they're bound to a date (such as with Worlds distributions). This means it's usually fine to check for news on pokemon.com or fan sites once a week or even once a month (as they tend to be announced a few month in advance).
Once the distribution period is over, there is no legal way to get the event. You can only trade online to get the Pokémon someone else got there, but the event is gone for good.

Most event exclusive Pokémon are being distributed again after some time, though. The newer the Pokémon, the smaller the chances are it'll be distributed again, so if you missed an event by just a few months, you'll probably have to wait for quite a while until there is another event with it.

One last important detail is that events are usually only available for the latest main series games, which currently means X or Y. Unless you own a copy of those, you sadly won't have access to events any more.

Comment: I would change the "*... are not obtainable in game by any means other than Cheat devices ... or glitches...*" to add **TRADES** (ok, the question is about events, but you CAN get those by Trades, No ?

Comment: That's right, I let the part a little lower influence me there :P

Comment: I made a REALLY small change, to avoid misleads (at least for non good English speakers). So people will not think that you can't trade with someone who get it from the official distribution.